# Is it possible to pass variables to a enum?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, enums

I have a class that validates strings using a "ValidationRequirements" data class and returns an Enum error message if its invalid.
Depending on what kind of requirements are passed the enum should adjust the string to match it.

ValidationRequirements:

```
data class ValidationRequirements(
        //--------CONFIG_REQUIREMENTS--------
        val PREFIX_STRING: String,
        val REQUIRED_LENGTH: Int,
        val MAXIMUM_LENGTH: Int,
        val REQUIRE_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS: Boolean,
        val REQUIRE_DIGITS: Boolean,
        val REQUIRE_LOWER_CASE: Boolean,
        val REQUIRE_UPPER_CASE: Boolean,
        val REQUIRE_SPACE_SEPARATION: Boolean
)
```

Enum:

```
enum class StringStrengthReport(private val errorMessage: String) {
            INVALID_EMAIL_FORMAT("Invalid email format\n"),
            TO_SHORT(" requires at least 6 characters\n"),
            LOWER_CASE_REQUIRED(" requires at least one lower case character\n"),
            UPPER_CASE_REQUIRED(" requires at least one upper case character\n"),
            DIGIT_REQUIRED(" requires at least one numeric character\n"),
            SPECIAL_CHARACTER_REQUIRED(" requires at least one special character (i.e !&?#%)\n"),
            MAX_LENGTH_EXCEEDED(" max length is 32 characters\n"),
            NULL_STRING(TO_SHORT.errorMessage),
            VALID(" is valid!\n");
}
```

Is it possible to pass the requirements to change min/max length for different kind of strings?

Answer (score 1):

Use sealed class instead:

```
sealed class StringStrengthReport(private val message: String) {
    override fun toString() = message
}
class InvalidEmailFormat(): StringStrengthReport("Invalid email format") 
class TooShort(val minLength: Int): StringStrengthReport("Requires at least $minLength characters")
```

Results in:

```
println(InvalidEmailFormat()) // Invalid email format
println(TooShort(7)) // Requires at least 7 characters
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to pass variables to enum, you actually need data class, not the enum, from my point of view.